# NGINX max upload has no effect

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-413

I'm using nginx proxy docker for my django project but
I'm getting **413 Request Entity Too Large** when uploading images more than about 3MB.

I put    `client_max_body_size 1024M;` in *htttp, server and location* in nginx.conf and default.conf  but it doesn't work at all.
Should I rewrite any other configs or uwsgi?